# Performance scaling on very large character matrix loop

Tags: r, performance, matrix, parallel-processing, vectorization

I have a very large character matrix in R, approximately [500000, 5], containing names. Each row may contain duplicate names. I'd like to know how many distinct names there are on each row. As far as I know, I can't vectorize any of the functions in this loop, right?

For example:

```
sampleNames <- c("Bob", "Elliot", "Sarah")


# Dimensions [100000, 5]
mat <- matrix(sampleNames[round(runif(500000, 1, 3))], ncol = 5)

NamesPerRow <- vector()

startTime <- Sys.time()
for(i in 1:dim(mat)[1]){
  NamesPerRow[i] <- length(unique(mat[i,])) 
}
Sys.time() - startTime
```

This takes only 20 seconds on my machine. Very tolerable. However, if the matrix has 5 times as many rows, the loop takes much longer than 100 seconds:

```
sampleNames <- c("Bob", "Elliot", "Sarah")

# Dimensions [500000, 5]
mat <- matrix(sampleNames[round(runif(2500000, 1, 3))], ncol = 5)


NamesPerRow <- vector()

startTime <- Sys.time()
for(i in 1:dim(mat)[1]){
  NamesPerRow[i] <- length(unique(mat[i,])) 
}
Sys.time() - startTime
```

This takes 13.12 minutes on my machine. 40 times longer than the 100000x5 matrix. Outrageous!

Any tricks I can use to perform these operations much quicker? Can I indeed vectorize anything here? Is this something I can fix with multi-threading (I'm not familiar)?

Also, what's going on here? Is it typical for computing time to increase at a much faster rate than the data I'm operating on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `rowTabulates` from `matrixStats` package

```
# Dimensions [500000, 5]
mat <- matrix(sampleNames[round(runif(2500000, 1, 3))], ncol = 5)
library(matrixStats)
startTime <- Sys.time()
mat1 <- matrix(match(mat, sampleNames), ncol=5)
b <- rowSums(rowTabulates(mat1)!=0)
Sys.time() - startTime
# Time difference of 0.2012889 secs
```

`apply()` by @Richard Scriven

```
startTime <- Sys.time()
a <- apply(mat, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)))
Sys.time() - startTime
# Time difference of 4.231503 secs
all.equal(a, b)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can shave quite a bit of time off by using `apply()`  It's designed for use on matrices.  But here you can also shave a lot of time simply by allocating the return vector, instead of building it in the loop.

```
sampleNames <- c("Bob", "Elliot", "Sarah")
# Dimensions [100000, 5]
mat <- matrix(sampleNames[round(runif(500000, 1, 3))], ncol = 5)
```

Here's where we allocate the return vector for the `for()` loop.

```
## instead of writing the generic vector() call
NamesPerRow <- vector("integer", nrow(mat))
```

Now with your current method, we have:

```
system.time({
  for(i in seq_along(NamesPerRow)) { ## seq_along() also slightly faster
    NamesPerRow[i] <- length(unique(mat[i,])) 
  }
})
#  user  system elapsed 
# 1.144   0.000   1.127
```

And with `apply()`

```
system.time({
  a <- apply(mat, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)))
})
#  user  system elapsed
# 1.012   0.000   0.993
```

Check:

```
identical(NamesPerRow, a)
# [1] TRUE
```

So just the simple act of allocating the vector can save a ton of time.

Comment: Wow, this reduced the time from 13+ minutes to 14 seconds! That's on a 500000 x 5 matrix. Thanks!

Comment: @nsw - Please see my update, as well as the other new answers

Answer (score 2):

Just to offer a third suggestion, you can use Rcpp:

```
library('Rcpp');

sampleNames <- c('Bob','Elliot','Sarah');
set.seed(1); mat <- matrix(sampleNames[round(runif(2500000,1,3))],ncol=5); ## 500000x5
head(mat);
##      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
## [1,] "Elliot" "Elliot" "Bob"    "Elliot" "Elliot"
## [2,] "Elliot" "Sarah"  "Elliot" "Sarah"  "Elliot"
## [3,] "Elliot" "Elliot" "Elliot" "Bob"    "Bob"
## [4,] "Sarah"  "Bob"    "Bob"    "Sarah"  "Sarah"
## [5,] "Bob"    "Elliot" "Bob"    "Bob"    "Bob"
## [6,] "Sarah"  "Bob"    "Elliot" "Elliot" "Elliot"
cppFunction('
    IntegerVector distinctByRow(IntegerMatrix mat) {
        IntegerVector res(mat.nrow());
        if (mat.ncol() == 0) return res;
        std::vector<int> buf(mat.ncol());
        for (size_t r = 0; r < mat.nrow(); ++r) {
            IntegerMatrix::Row row = mat.row(r);
            buf.assign(row.begin(),row.end());
            std::sort(buf.begin(),buf.end());
            int count = 1;
            for (size_t c = 1; c < mat.ncol(); ++c)
                if (buf[c] != buf[c-1])
                    ++count;
            res(r) = count;
        }
        return res;
    }
');
res.rcpp <- distinctByRow(matrix(match(mat,sampleNames),nrow(mat)));
head(res.rcpp);
## [1] 2 2 2 2 2 3
```

---

## Performance

```
## libs
library('Rcpp');
library('matrixStats');

## funcs
f.loop.grow <- function(mat) { res <- vector(); for (i in seq_len(nrow(mat))) res[i] <- length(unique(mat[i,])); res; };
f.loop.prealloc <- function(mat) { res <- vector('integer',nrow(mat)); for (i in seq_len(nrow(mat))) res[i] <- length(unique(mat[i,])); res; };
f.apply <- function(mat) apply(mat,1,function(x) length(unique(x)));
f.rowtab <- function(mat) rowSums(rowTabulates(matrix(match(mat,sampleNames),nrow(mat))) != 0L);
f.rcpp <- function(mat) distinctByRow(matrix(match(mat,sampleNames),nrow(mat)));

## data
sampleNames <- c('Bob','Elliot','Sarah');
set.seed(1); mat <- matrix(sampleNames[round(runif(2500000,1,3))],ncol=5); ## 500000x5

## proof of correctness
all.equal(f.loop.grow(mat),f.loop.prealloc(mat));
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(f.loop.prealloc(mat),f.apply(mat));
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(f.apply(mat),f.rowtab(mat));
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(f.rowtab(mat),f.rcpp(mat));
## [1] TRUE

## timing
microbenchmark(f.loop.grow(mat),f.loop.prealloc(mat),f.apply(mat),f.rowtab(mat),f.rcpp(mat),times=3L);
## Unit: milliseconds
##                  expr        min         lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
##      f.loop.grow(mat) 96624.4954 99011.9452 100625.0517 101399.3950 102625.3299 103851.2648     3
##  f.loop.prealloc(mat)  3572.0831  3574.6325   3616.9598   3577.1820   3639.3982   3701.6145     3
##          f.apply(mat)  3329.4926  3410.6111   3486.2511   3491.7296   3564.6304   3637.5311     3
##         f.rowtab(mat)   259.8664   288.6030    299.2716    317.3395    318.9742    320.6089     3
##           f.rcpp(mat)   122.1257   124.6957    163.4774    127.2657    184.1532    241.0407     3
```

---

## Performance 2

I was curious how the `matrixStats::rowTabulates()` function (used in ExperimenteR's answer) worked internally, so I looked at the source. Here it is, from `R/rowTabulates.R`:

```
rowTabulates <- function(x, values=NULL, ...) {
    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    # Validate arguments
    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    # Argument 'x':
    if (is.integer(x)) {
    } else if (is.raw(x)) {
    } else {
        stop("Argument 'x' is not of type integer or raw: ", class(x)[1]);
    }

    # Argument 'values':
    if (is.null(values)) {
        values <- as.vector(x);
        values <- unique(values);
        if (is.raw(values)) {
            values <- as.integer(values);
            values <- sort(values);
            # WORKAROUND: Cannot use "%#x" because it gives an error OSX with
            # R v2.9.0 devel (2009-01-13 r47593b) at R-forge. /HB 2009-06-20
            names <- sprintf("%x", values);
            names <- paste("0x", names, sep="");
            values <- as.raw(values);
        } else {
            values <- sort(values);
            names <- as.character(values);
        }
    } else {
        if (is.raw(values)) {
            names <- sprintf("%x", as.integer(values));
            names <- paste("0x", names, sep="");
        } else {
            names <- as.character(values);
        }
    }


    nbrOfValues <- length(values);
    counts <- matrix(0L, nrow=nrow(x), ncol=nbrOfValues);
    colnames(counts) <- names;

    for (kk in seq(length=nbrOfValues)) {
        counts[,kk] <- rowCounts(x, value=values[kk], ...);
    }

    counts;
}
```

The most interesting part is the `for` loop at the end; they're actually looping through each unique value in the input and getting row counts! I realized that this might cause the function to exhibit poor performance if there were many unique values in the input, as opposed to a case like the OP's example data where we only have three. So I did another performance test, this time with 1000 unique values, and I also decided to try with fewer rows and more columns. As you can see, the results are the polar opposite of what I got above. This really shows how algorithms can behave very differently depending on what data you throw at them!

```
## data 2 -- more names and columns
rstr <- function(N,charset=letters,lf=function(N) runif(N,trunc(lmin)-0.5,trunc(lmax)+0.5),lmin=1,lmax=10) {
    charset <- as.character(charset);
    len <- sort(as.integer(round(pmin(lmax,pmax(lmin,lf(N))))));
    rl <- rle(len);
    sample(do.call(c,Map(function(len,num) if (len == 0) rep('',num) else do.call(paste0,as.data.frame(matrix(sample(charset,len*num,replace=T),num))), rl$values, rl$lengths )));
};
set.seed(1); N <- 1e3; sampleNames <- rstr(N);
head(sampleNames);
## [1] "wcbzjxq"    "etxjz"      "ompognqack" "eufkli"     "rworpwkk"   "ghw"
mat <- matrix(sample(sampleNames,2500000,replace=T),ncol=500); ## 5000x500
head(mat[,1:6]);
##      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]         [,5]      [,6]
## [1,] "qgrb"     "gb"       "pmiula"    "wrx"        "yr"      "kejil"
## [2,] "ivaqaaek" "alen"     "woenvkgkh" "zkocecowl"  "mjgv"    "ejqks"
## [3,] "nvz"      "yr"       "kyxmjjrnn" "vfzc"       "tnm"     "cnw"
## [4,] "ut"       "jgexsepo" "jh"        "ejqks"      "iy"      "galtchwmh"
## [5,] "ppxe"     "bnpqxbj"  "nvz"       "ruulsigdzq" "hpuw"    "rjsofvjev"
## [6,] "bdoxqim"  "qr"       "mgkkku"    "agjdgjhv"   "bdoxqim" "bdoxqim"

## proof of correctness 2
all.equal(f.loop.grow(mat),f.loop.prealloc(mat));
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(f.loop.prealloc(mat),f.apply(mat));
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(f.apply(mat),f.rowtab(mat));
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(f.rowtab(mat),f.rcpp(mat));
## [1] TRUE

## timing 2
microbenchmark(f.loop.grow(mat),f.loop.prealloc(mat),f.apply(mat),f.rowtab(mat),f.rcpp(mat),times=3L);
## Unit: milliseconds
##                  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
##      f.loop.grow(mat)  153.3568  157.6669  167.5521  161.9770  174.6497  187.3223     3
##  f.loop.prealloc(mat)  141.1644  142.8239  144.1546  144.4834  145.6497  146.8159     3
##          f.apply(mat)  166.2976  177.0187  195.1381  187.7397  209.5583  231.3770     3
##         f.rowtab(mat) 2590.8117 2623.3600 2665.5511 2655.9082 2702.9207 2749.9333     3
##           f.rcpp(mat)  197.6206  197.7765  202.5478  197.9324  205.0113  212.0903     3
```

Comment: `matrix(unclass(factor(mat)),nrow(mat))` takes most of the time for `Rcpp` solution, otherwise it should be very fast.

Comment: Thanks @ExperimenteR! I didn't realize how adversely my `factor()` call affected performance. After improving my solution by stealing your excellent `match(mat,sampleNames)` idea, I now find my Rcpp solution performs the best of the group. Thank you! +1 to your answer :)